# Flask - Not found

Tags: python, flask

I've built a small flask app which listens on HTTP POST requests and sends data to MQTT. But I can not get it running on the local network.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python


from flask import Flask, request
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import ssl


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port=5000)

@app.route('/mqtt', methods=['GET'])

def get_id():

  topic = request.args.get('topic')
  temp = request.args.get('temp')
  hum = request.args.get('hum')
  pre = request.args.get('pre')
  auth = {
         'username':"user",
         'password':"pw
  tls = {
         'ca_certs':"/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",
         'tls_version':ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
       }
  publish.single(topic,
  payload= temp + " " +  hum + " " + pre,
  hostname="domain",
  client_id="REST_API",
  auth=auth,
  tls=tls,
  port=8883,
  protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)

  return("OK")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Query looks like:

```
curl --noproxy -x POST "192.168.2.56:5000/mqtt?topic=simcom7000e1&temp=25&hum=10&pre=99"
```

Error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

If I comment out:

```
@app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

And run:

```
curl --noproxy -x POST "localhost:5000/mqtt?topic=simcom7000e1&temp=25&hum=10&pre=99"
```

Then it works. To me this is really strange. What could be the issue?

Comment: seems like you are running different `curl` commands , on the second one you run `localhost` while in the first one you run `192.168...` try and run the same command and see what happen without commenting out the `app.run...`, and another thing - you just added route to `GET` messages and not `POST` , try and fix that too.

Answer (score 0):

You routed it with `GET` but try to put a request with `POST`. And you may try to register with following:

```
@app.route('/mqtt', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python


from flask import Flask, request
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import ssl


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/mqtt', methods=['GET'])

def get_id():

  topic = request.args.get('topic')
  temp = request.args.get('temp')
  hum = request.args.get('hum')
  pre = request.args.get('pre')
  auth = {
         'username':"user",
         'password':"pw
  tls = {
         'ca_certs':"/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",
         'tls_version':ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
       }
  publish.single(topic,
  payload= temp + " " +  hum + " " + pre,
  hostname="domain",
  client_id="REST_API",
  auth=auth,
  tls=tls,
  port=8883,
  protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)

  return("OK")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True), host = '0.0.0.0', port=5000
```